# How to use BufferedImage in android for apache.common.imaging

Tags: java, android, apache, bufferedimage

i am using a method from the apache.common.imaging in which the BufferedImage is used, i know that BufferedImage is not part of the android classes since awt package is not available but i need bufferedimage for that method any ways to achieve this?

The method is as follows:

```
JpegImageParser parser=  Imaging.getBufferedImage(sourceFile);
```

you can find the source of the library [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/imaging/Imaging.html#line.1230) is there a way to port that project or any workaround to get this method working?

Answer (score 0):

Android has other libraries that provide this functionality. In particular, Picaso is quite popular and easy to use.

Comment: I don't need image processing my intension is to extract the xmp data from the image